# Why is the css rule not valid for the first item in the list?

Tags: css, list

Why is the css rule not valid for the first item in the list? Why is the css rule not valid for the first item in the list? Why is the css rule not valid for the first item in the list? Why is the css rule not valid for the first item in the list?

```css
ol {
   padding-left: 10px;
   margin-top: 1em;
   margin-bottom: 1em;
  
}

ol + li {
 background-color:yellow;
 
}

ol > li  > ol > li {
      padding-left: 10px;
}

ol {
   list-style: none;
   counter-reset: li;
}
li:before {
   counter-increment: li;
   content: counters(li, ".") ". ";
}
```

```html
<ol>

<li>colors1</li>
<ol>
<li>green</li>
<li>green</li>
</ol>


<li>colors2</li>
<ol>
<li>yellow</li>
<li>yellow</li>
</ol>



<li>colors3</li>
<ol>

<li>red</li>
<li>red</li>
<li>red</li>
</ol>
</ol>
```

Why is the rule not valid for the first item in the list?

Comment: Your first `li` doesn't follow a `ol`, it is the child of one. For example if you did this, your current code would work (although this is NOT a solution). `<ol><ol></ol><li>colors1</li>...`

Answer (score 0):

```css
ol {
   padding-left: 10px;
   margin-top: 1em;
   margin-bottom: 1em;
  
}
ul > li {
 background-color:yellow;
 
}
ol > li  > ol > li {
      padding-left: 10px;
}
li:before {
   counter-increment: li;
   content: counters(li, ".") ". ";
}

ul,ol  {
   list-style: none;
   counter-reset: li;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>colors1</li>
<ol>
<li>green</li>
<li>green</li>
<li>green</li>
<li>green</li>
</ol>
<li>colors2</li>
<ol>
<li>yellow</li>
<li>yellow</li>
<li>yellow</li>
<li>yellow</li>
</ol>
<li>colors3</li>
<ol>
<li>red</li>
<li>red</li>
<li>red</li>
</ol>
<li>colors4</li>
<ol>
<li>magenta</li>
<li>magenta</li>
<li>magenta</li>
</ol>
</ul>

</ul>
```

Comment: I share some solution, but it not may be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ol {
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  counter-reset: li;
}

.container>li {
  background-color: yellow;
}

ol>ol>li { 
  padding-left: 10px;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: li;
  content: counter(li, ".") ". ";
}
```

```html
<ol class="container">

  <li>colors1</li>
  <ol>
    <li>green</li>
    <li>green</li>
  </ol>


  <li>colors2</li>
  <ol>
    <li>yellow</li>
    <li>yellow</li>
  </ol>



  <li>colors3</li>
  <ol>
    <li>red</li>
    <li>red</li>
    <li>red</li>
  </ol>
  
</ol>
```